# How to change gem installation location to right location?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Some how recently my OS X Rails ruby gem bundler location got changed to app/vendor/bundle. I want it back in ~/.bundle. And is '~/.bundle' the normal installation location? Or should it be somewhere in rbenv?
What is the exact command to change it back for all future installs?
I've tried 'bundle install --system' and it didn't change anything. Same with a few other commands.

Here is my 'bundle env':

```
Bundler       2.1.4
  Platforms   ruby, x86_64-darwin-19
Ruby          2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision) [x86_64-darwin19]
  Full Path   /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/ruby
  Config Dir  /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/etc
RubyGems      3.1.2
  Gem Home    /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  Gem Path    /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.7.0:/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0
  User Home   /Users/me
  User Path   /Users/me/.gem/ruby/2.7.0
  Bin Dir     /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin
Tools         
  Git         2.25.2
  RVM         not installed
  rbenv       rbenv 1.1.2
  chruby      not installed
```

### Bundler Build Metadata

```
Built At          2020-01-05
Git SHA           xxx
Released Version  true
```

### Bundler settings

```
git.allow_insecure
  Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): "true"
path
  Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"
set
  Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): "path vendor/bundle"
build.nokogiri
  Set for the current user (/Users/me/.bundle/config): "--use-system-libraries"
```

Comment: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html

Comment: I've looked at that page. It tells me every different way to make changes to bundle config but I don't see anywhere where it shows me how to change bundle config back to it's original default of when it was installed.

Comment: Delete the config. And delete the config in your app directory as well.